# Twilio VideoChat: User can't connect to room

Tags: javascript, twilio

Currently, I am creating a programmable videochat. The problem is that when creating a room, only one of the enters and the other one never does.

The users are in a chat room already where they type to eachother so I just used that same room code to create the Twilio video chat room. I confirmed that they both have the same room ids to join.

```
const videoTwilio = Twilio.Video;

$(document).ready(function () {

    var roomId = $("#roomId").val();
    var token = $("#token").val();


    videoTwilio.connect(token, {
        name: roomId
    }).then(room => {
        console.log('Connected to Room ' + roomId + " token is: " + token);

        room.participants.forEach(participantConnected);
        room.on('participantConnected', participantConnected => {
            console.log("Remote participant is: " + participantConnected);
        });

        room.on('participantDisconnected', participantDisconnected => {
            console.log("participant disconnected");
        });


room.once('disconnected', error => room.participants.forEach(participantDisconnected));
    });
}
```

Comment: Do all your participants have unique tokens? Each participant must have a unique token.

Comment: Hey @efoc, I am a developer evangelist at Twilio and would love to help. Did you see the comment above? Are you generating the token in a server side application and using different identities for your users?